# create home screen shortcut android

Tags: android

I want to create a shortcut for an android app.

I want to understand that when I press the shortcut it would take me to the latest activity.The behaviour should be the same as to when we long press on the home screen which pops up the recent activity and when you press on yours it takes you to the latest activity.

Any help !!
Thanks